# Ansi-C C99 Interface with struct

Tags: c, struct, information-hiding

I'm mainly use Labwindows CVI from National Instruments as my compiler.

I have to make an interface to a device and started down the road of making looks for structs for all the different registers.

```
// Interface.h

typedef enum Color{
    White,
    Black,
    Blue
};

typedef struct Register1{
    int Bit1:1;
    int Bit2:2;
    Color col;
} Register1;

// Interface.c

BuildSendMessage(Register1 temp)
{
    unsigned int iTemp;

    iTemp = temp.Bit1 << 7 + temp.Bit2 << 5 + temp.col; 
}

// sample.c

Register1 reg1;

reg1.Bit1 = 0;
reg1.Bit2 = 1;
reg1.col = White;

// Pass to function where message is built up

BuildSendMessage(reg1);
```

I then populate the struct in the calling function and then pass the struct into a function where I do all the bit shifting, append the address, etc. onto the message and ship it out over the comm interface.

Can this be improved and should I do more information hiding and have a function populate the struct? I've been doing a lot of reading and this could definitely use some improvement.

Comment: Your information is too limited to give a good answer. For now, I suggest you continue on your way and do what you think is best. Then, if it works, go and "refactor" the code (i.e., learn and build a new version).

Comment: Note that the layout of bitfield-structs is very badly defined in C. For hardware-registers, use `stdint.h` **unsigned** fixed-width types, masks and bit-operators. Be careful with integer promotions.

Comment: What I am trying to do is I have a device that I talk to over tcp it has a document explaining what each register does. 

I have some code where I will setup instrumentation, write to this device, plot data, etc. Other people may use this code later on in the future.

My plan was to fill in the fields of the struct as I need to setup up the device and then pass that to a function where full message is built up.

It seems this structure should be hidden from the final user and functions with generic fields should be exposed.

Comment: `iTemp = temp.Bit1 << 7 + temp.Bit2 << 5 + temp.col; ` -->> `iTemp = (temp.Bit1 << 7) + (temp.Bit2 << 5) + (temp.col & 0x0f); ` Your compiler should warn you about this

Answer (score 0):

> What I am trying to do is I have a device that I talk to over tcp it
>   has a document explaining what each register does.

…

> I then populate the struct in the calling function and then pass the
>   struct into a function where I do all the bit shifting, append the
>   address, etc. onto the message and ship it out over the comm
>   interface.
>
> Can this be improved and should I do more information hiding and have
>   a function populate the struct?

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_hiding):

> In computer science, **information hiding** is the principle of
>   segregation of the *design decisions* in a computer program that are
>   most likely to change, thus protecting other parts of the program from
>   extensive modification if the design decision is changed. The
>   protection involves providing a stable interface which protects the
>   remainder of the program from the implementation (the details that are
>   most likely to change).

What each register does in the device is not likely to change, and if it eventually should change, other parts of the program would probably need modification anyway, so there is no point in doing "more information hiding".